# How to copy cell from one row to another in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

```
Range("A7:C17").Copy Range("F2")
```

I just want to copy data from A7 to F2; B7 TO F3 and C7 to F4 in same sheet. 
I used the code above. but if i am adding one more row (i.e, A18 B18 C18), then its not working. Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have as many rows in C as in A

`Range("A7", Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy Range("F2")`

If not,

```
Range("A7", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 3).Copy Range("F2")
```

If you only want the values and not the formatting,

```
If Range("F2") <> vbNullString Then
    Range("F2", Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 3).ClearContents
End If

With Range("A7", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 3)
    Range("F2").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, its working only if i am adding 1 row. But if i am deleting the same row, it is not updating and last row value is showing twice. How to resolve it

Comment: I've added a line to the last block of code which clears any existing cells in F2 and down.

Comment: bro, its deleting the F1 G1 H1 cells. how to solve it

Comment: I think that can only happen if F2 is empty - try it now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Transpose`, try the code below:

```
Range("A7:C17").Copy
Range("F2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but why does OP need `Transpose`?

Comment: @CallumDA look at the structure of the copied data and the paste

Comment: Oh, have I misunderstood? I can see the description does suggest transposing now, but the pic suggests not.

Comment: @SJR, that's what I assumed too, even though I now see that OP has asked for `F2`, `F3` & `F4`. Not sure if that's a typo